# Cabal not present after latest Haskell install

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am trying latest Haskell from [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_8_1.html#windows64) on Windows7. I downloaded ghc-8.8.1-x86_64-unknown-mingw32.tar.xz (377.3 MB) and untarred it in a folder and added bin folder path to environment.

Now I can run ghc but cabal or cabal-install are not there.

Although I:\ghc-8.8.1\lib\Cabal-3.0.0.0 is there in package but there is no cabal.exe or cabal-install.exe

How can I get an run cabal in this setup? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you just got GHC (with source for cabal). You probably want the Haskell platform instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GHC is just the compiler and a set of core libraries and executables, of which `cabal`-the-program is not one. The `Cabal` you found is a library for package management. The `cabal` *program* is part of the [`cabal-install`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install) package, and it depends on the `Cabal` library. Without `cabal-install` installed, you cannot `cabal install cabal-install`. Instead, you have to manually download the `cabal` program from [the website](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html). You can build it from source or you can use one of the pre-built binaries.